# Animating a line in Three.js with lineTo and curveTo

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm a three.js newbie and I'm coming from Processing/p5.js (so I'm a bit spoiled on animating loops). I'm trying to create something like this simple stretching pill shape:

[Stretching pill shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWnfZ.gif)

This is what I cobbled together from some things I found online. I just have the 'O' shape. I'm trying to get the variable oHeight to be the variable that causes the fluxing back and forth with a Math.sin.

Do I need to update the path? Or the bufferGeometry? Or the THREE.path?

Sorry this code is so messy. Just starting out!

```
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var curve;
        var path;
        var oHeight = 0;
        var delta = 0;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 600;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            path = new THREE.Path();

            path.lineTo( 0, 0 );
            path.quadraticCurveTo( 0, 20, 20, 20 );
            path.lineTo( 40, 20 );
            path.quadraticCurveTo( 60,20, 60,0);
            path.lineTo(60,-40-oHeight);
            path.quadraticCurveTo( 60,-60-oHeight, 40,-60-oHeight);
            path.lineTo(20,-60-oHeight);
            path.quadraticCurveTo(0,-60,0,-40-oHeight);
            path.lineTo(0,0);

            var points = path.getPoints();

            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );

            curve = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

            scene.add( curve );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            delta +=.1;
            oHeight = Math.sin(delta)*20;
            line.needUpdate = true; //is this where I went wrong?

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no object `line` in your code and there is no mystic reference from the object `geometry` to the `oHeight`. The `THREE.Path` is only a temporary object, which contains the information, that is needed to create the [`BufferGeoemtry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry). Note, at the end the vertices of the `geometry` are stored in an array buffer on the GPU.

You have to create the path in the `animate` function and to set it to the `BufferGeoemtry`. So the geometry is recreated in every frame:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    delta +=.1;
    oHeight = Math.sin(delta)*20;

    path = new THREE.Path();
    path.lineTo( 0, 0 );
    path.quadraticCurveTo( 0, 20, 20, 20 );
    path.lineTo( 40, 20 );
    path.quadraticCurveTo( 60,20, 60,0);
    path.lineTo(60,-40-oHeight);
    path.quadraticCurveTo( 60,-60-oHeight, 40,-60-oHeight);
    path.lineTo(20,-60-oHeight);
    path.quadraticCurveTo(0,-60-oHeight,0,-40-oHeight);
    path.lineTo(0,0);

    geometry.dispose();
    geometry.setFromPoints( path.getPoints() );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var curve;
var path;
var oHeight = 0;
var delta = 0;
var geometry;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 600;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );

    curve = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

    scene.add( curve );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.onresize = resize;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    delta +=.1;
    oHeight = Math.sin(delta)*20;

    path = new THREE.Path();
    path.lineTo( 0, 0 );
    path.quadraticCurveTo( 0, 20, 20, 20 );
    path.lineTo( 40, 20 );
    path.quadraticCurveTo( 60,20, 60,0);
    path.lineTo(60,-40-oHeight);
    path.quadraticCurveTo( 60,-60-oHeight, 40,-60-oHeight);
    path.lineTo(20,-60-oHeight);
    path.quadraticCurveTo(0,-60-oHeight,0,-40-oHeight);
    path.lineTo(0,0);
    
    geometry.dispose();
    geometry.setFromPoints( path.getPoints() );
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function resize() {   
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow. Of course. Just like in Processing. Ugh. Thanks so much.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: is it not necessery to call `.dispose()` on a geometry? like in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=memory#webgl_test_memory